# Python: Seeking to EOL in file not working

Tags: python, csv, io, seek, chunking

I have this method:

```
def get_chunksize(path):
    """
    Breaks a file into chunks and yields the chunk sizes.
    Number of chunks equals the number of available cores.
    Ensures that each chunk ends at an EOL.
    """
    size = os.path.getsize(path)
    cores = mp.cpu_count()
    chunksize = size/cores # gives truncated integer

    f = open(path)
    while 1:
        start = f.tell()
        f.seek(chunksize, 1) # Go to the next chunk
        s = f.readline() # Ensure the chunk ends at the end of a line
        yield start, f.tell()-start
        if not s:
            break
```

It is supposed to break a file into chunks and return the start of the chunk (in bytes) and the chunk size.

Crucially, the end of a chunk should correspond to the end of a line (which is why the `f.readline()` behaviour is there), but I am finding that my chunks are not seeking to an EOL at all.

The purpose of the method is to then read chunks which can be passed to a `csv.reader` instance (via `StringIO`) for further processing.

I've been unable to spot anything obviously wrong with the function...any ideas why it is not moving to the EOL?

I came up with this rather clunky alternative:

```
def line_chunker(path):
    size = os.path.getsize(path)
    cores = mp.cpu_count()
    chunksize = size/cores # gives truncated integer

    f = open(path)

    while True:
        part = f.readlines(chunksize)
        yield csv.reader(StringIO("".join(part)))
        if not part:
            break
```

This will split the file into chunks with a csv reader for each chunk, but the last chunk is always empty (??) and having to join the list of strings back together is rather clunky.

Comment: My first guess would be that `.readline()` is using a buffer. That means it always reads, say, 4096 bytes and then returns the first line from this.

Comment: if using a buffer, doesn't it then seek back to where the EOL character is before returning the line, so that a subsequent call to ``f.tell()`` would give the correct position? Surely this behaviour would be required anyway so that `.readline` always reads from the start of the line (when called multiple times)

Comment: Set `chunksize` to something small (1 or 10). The code above should then read the input line by line. Do you see a pattern in that `f.tell()` returns after `f.readline()`?

Comment: Buffering is done at a lower level, python has no need to know the exact position of the caret when it calls `readline`, the OS handles that.

Comment: added an alternative chunking example to the question, but this one doesnt work ideally either

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> if not s:
>         break
> ```

Instead of looking at `s` to see if you're at the end of the file, you should look if you've reached the end of the file by using:

`if size == f.tell(): break`

this should fix it.  I wouldn't depend on a CSV file having a single record per line though.  I've worked with several CSV files that have strings with new-lines:

```
first,last,message
sue,ee,hello
bob,builder,"hello,
this is some text
that I entered"
jim,bob,I'm not so creative...
```

Notice the 2nd record (bob) spans across 3 lines.  csv.reader can handle this.  If the idea is to do some cpu intensive work on a csv.  I'd create an array of threads, each with a buffer of n records.  have the csv.reader pass a record to each thread using round-robin, skipping a thread if its buffer is full.
Hope this helps - enjoy.